# How to fit smaller spheres inside a 3D shape such as Mickey Mouse?

Tags: matlab, physics, ragged-tensors

I am looking at a problem that takes in an argument of a 3D STL file  -> Shape and (rmin -> Minimum Radius) and fits in a maximum number of spheres inside the shape. The function should spit out position and radius (x,y,z,r). One such program is called CLUMP-https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/98314-clump-code-library-to-generate-multi-sphere-particles

However, the clump is not performing so well for a Mickey Mouse-type shape. I am attaching my findings below. My aim is to get the [TensorA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTLmi.png) Center of the reaction matrix to be a diagonal one and the rest of the elements to be zero.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is the clump not performing so well on a Mickey Mouse type shape? What do you not like about the clump result? What would you like to have instead? Why are you interested in Mikey Mouse type shapes? What is the Tensor A center of the reaction matrix? Why do you want it to be diagonal? With more context this can become a useful question.

Comment: Thank you. I will reform the question shortly.